# how to pass NumberPicker value (onValueChange) through Data Binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding, numberpicker

Android Number picker has: `onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal)`

how to pass those parameters (NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) to my viewmodel through databind?

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable name="vm" type="com.my.view.model.MainActivityVM" />
</data>
/* ... bla ...*/
<NumberPicker
    android:onValueChange="@{() -> vm.callMethod(/*???whats here???*/)}" />
```

I want to catch the new value in my view model everytime it changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
    android:onValueChange="@{(picker,oldv,newv) -> viewModel.onValChange(oldv, newv)}">
```

I chose to have the signature of my `ViewModel` class take only the old and new values, not the NumberPicker.  That's up to you.

Comment: it Works! Thank you

Comment: I don't get where the `picker` comes from

Comment: @MwBakker That's the View (`NumberPicker`) itself. That's a mandatory parameter given to all listeners, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use two-way databinding like with any other natively adapted view.

```
<NumberPicker
    android:value="@={vm.observableIntVariable}"
    />
```

Don't forget the usual [two-way requirements](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)!